# Creating dynamic anchor tag and triggering it in new tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a pdf link in ajax response and I want to trigger in manually. I am using this code

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = data.PDF_INVOICE;
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
link.download = data.PDF_INVOICE.split(/[/ ]+/).pop();
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

I want to trigger the download in new tab but `link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');` is not working. What can be the issue?

Comment: why not just `window.open`?

Comment: Have you tried `link.click()`?

Comment: I want to download it as well

Comment: may be you have pop up blocker or adblocker. that sometimes the issue. 
Or use a hidden iframe, just trigger it it will directly show download

Comment: My code download is working absilutely fine. I want to trigger the download in new tab. that's all

Comment: May I suggest adding class  to your element and then using JQ to add target blank `$('a').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: I don't think you can set a downlink in new tab, it is one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following:

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "";
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
link.download = "http://url-to-pdf";
link.click();
```

Put empty `href` and use `link.click()`

Comment: How is that different behaviour than OP's one? There isn't  as i can see it

Comment: It's still not opening in new tab.

Comment: You can create another page, which take download link as parameter and download the file. Then you can open that page from this link instead of directly downloading the PDF.